# ¿Cómo hacer que el valor en un ToDo List dé false desde el arranque?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo una to do list en react js para practicar. La lista funciona bien, el problema es que yo le agregué un confirm de felicitaciones que aparezca cuando hayas completado todas tus tareas y que si lo aceptas las borra. El problema es que el confirm sale cuando la lista está vacía, entonces cuando inicia la app sale sin tener tareas, y cuando vacías la lista entra en un loop del que no para de salir a menos que le des cancelar.

Link de vercel para poder ver el problema: https://to-do-list-plum-two.vercel.app/

Link de github: https://github.com/guidomora/To-Do-List.git

Código:

```
// Funcion para chequear cuando se completan todas las tareas

const checkStatus = tasks.every((task) => task.completed === true);

//  Funcion que estuve probando(pero me rompe todo el codigo) para que no salte el cartel cuando la lista de tareas esta vacia
const checkTasks = () => {
  if (tasks.length === 0) {
    setTasks(tasks.completed = false)
    console.log(tasks.completed)
  }
}
checkTasks()

return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={addTask} />
        <div className="tasks-list-container">
          {tasks.map((task) => (
            <Tasks
              key={task.id}
              id={task.id}
              text={task.text}
              completed={task.completed}
              deleteTask={deleteTask}
              completeTask={completeTask}
            />
          ))}
          {tasks.length ? (
            <button className="clear-button" onClick={clearAll}>
              Borrar Todas las tareas
            </button>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>{checkStatus === true ? tasksFinished() : <></>}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: ¿Por qué creaste una pregunta nueva? Ya tienes una activa.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [React js: como hacer que cuando arranca mi app un booleano de false?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/556459/react-js-como-hacer-que-cuando-arranca-mi-app-un-booleano-de-false)

Comment: @Jacobo reporté la otra pregunta como duplicada de esta, ya que esta, en teoría, es más "completa".

Comment: buenas! elimine la anterior, ya que esta responde mi pregunta. Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El problema radica en que [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) retorna `true` para una lista vacía, esto queda expreso en la documentación:

> Nota: Precaución: ¡Llamar este método en un array vacío devuelve true
> para cualquier condición!

Entonces hay que agregar una condición adicional para que validar según el largo de la lista de tareas, algo como:

```
const checkStatus = tasks.every((task) => task.completed === true) && tasks.length > 0;
```

Resultado:
https://to-do-list-pink-delta.vercel.app/

Comment: no lo puedo creer que era eso,  como no se me ocurrio. muchas gracias de verdad!

Comment: Gracias por responder, aunque esta respuesta puede servir como guía, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle o una breve explicación de lo que hace el código y dónde iría, de ese modo la respuesta será de más utilidad para otros usuarios que puedan encontrarse con el mismo problema. Lee [answer] para más información.